# C++ client not receiving any data from Python server

Tags: python, c++, sockets, tcp, recv

I'm working on a project with a C++ client and a Python server.

```
int connecting(SOCKET s){
    WSADATA wsa;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        std::cout<<"WSA error";
        return 1;
    }
    if((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))==INVALID_SOCKET){
        std::cout<<"invalid socket";
        return 1;
    }
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.10");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(2424);

    if(connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server))!=0){
        std::cout<<"error connecting";
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

void recv_data(SOCKET socket){
    char buf[buflen];
    recv(socket, buf, buflen, 0);
    std::cout<<buf;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
   SOCKET s;
   connecting(s);
   recv_data(s);
}
```

Here's the very basic Python server.

```
import socket
import struct

s=socket.socket()
s.bind(("192.168.1.10", 2424))
s.listen(1)
c, a=s.accept()
print(f"{a}")
data="Hi from server"
c.send(data.encode())
```

After establishing the connection in the server, the `a` variable is printed. Nothing is received nor printed in the client-side. I tried putting in a loop the `recv()` function in the client but it does not work.

Comment: do recv() return read bytes ?
is it an encoding problem ?

Comment: i looked at some examples of this, the common tecnique is to pack data with **struct.pack()** but it doesn't work. Of course you need to send encoded data tho. I'm new to C++ and i couldn't find so much about cross-languages socket connections

Comment: change the signature of the methods to **int connecting(SOCKET& s)** and **void recv_data(SOCKET& socket)**. Now, since it's a pass by reference, I believe the data will be passed to the methods and processed correctly.

Comment: @vik your Python server exits immediately after sending data. This is a guess, but it might be that the OS kills the underlying socket and doesn't pass around correct TCP packets. Try adding long sleep at the end of the server to check this.

Comment: @freakish thank you for the answer but unfortunately the result doesn't change. Nothing is being received not printed. I used a **time.sleep()** but nothing.

Comment: @vik ok, in order to debug this you need to check `recv` return value for errors (which you should always be doing anyway).

Comment: @freakish -1, wondering what is the problem here.

Comment: @vik good, we're making progress. Now that you know that there's an error, you have to check `errno` variable. For that you need to `#include <errno.h>`. Unless you are using Windows, for which you have to use [WSAGetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsagetlasterror) function instead of errno.

Comment: @freakish really appreciating your help, `std::cout<<errno;` returns -10, doing `strerror(errno)` returns `No Error`

Comment: @vik sorry, it seems that you are using Windows, so you have to check WSAGetLastError (I've updated my previous comment) instead of errno. Yeah, cross platform error handling is annoying with C/C++.

Comment: @freakish **-110038**, in `strerror()` unknown error.

Comment: @freakish yes, #include `<Winsock2.h>` is in my code.

Comment: @vik ah, ok, actually what @TheApache said was correct. You need to change signature of `int connecting(SOCKET s)` function to `int connecting(SOCKET& s)`. Because you set `s` in that function but without reference changes never leave it. Still the error code is weird.

Comment: @freakish i had already tried chanching the signature but it still does not work.

Comment: UPDATE: i tried again the @TheApache solution. Now `std::cout<<strerror(WSAGetLastError());` returns **No Error** but still no data is received indeed the return value of the function `recv()` is 1.

Comment: And if i try to print `buf` for some reason *aP²* is printed. Makes me thing about an encoding problem.

Comment: @vik your problem now is that you misunderstand how `recv` works. When `recv` returns a positive number then it returns the amount of bytes it actually read. It does not necessarily read `buflen` bytes, anything between 0 and `buflen` may happen. So your `recv` call return `1` byte and your buffer is filled only with 1 char (the rest is undefined). You have to loop `recv`, fill the buffer chunk by chunk, until `recv` returns `0` which indicates that the connection was closed by the other side.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood argument passing by value...

```
void f(int x) {
    x = 5;
}

int main() {
    int j = 7;
    f(j);
    printf("%d\n", j);
}
```

What is `j`? **NOT 5!** The number 7 was passed into `f`, where it was stored in the variable `x`, and then the number 5 was stored in the variable `x`, which is not the variable `j`, so `j` was not changed.

You have this in your program:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
   SOCKET s;
   connecting(s);
   recv_data(s);
}
```

After the call `connecting(s)` what is `s`? **NOT A SOCKET!** Only the variable `s` inside the function `connecting` held a socket handle, and the variable `s` in `main` is not that variable, so it never got to hold a socket handle. You pass some uninitialized value to `recv_data`.

The function `recv` probably reads this random uninitialized value and returns an error code meaning "hey, that isn't a socket handle" but since your code never checked whether it returned an error code, you wouldn't know about this.